# Process.getErrorStream() doesn't work when the output of the batch is too large

Tags: java, batch-file

```
static String getTime(String command) throws IOException, Throwable{
    try{
        String completeComm=Userdir+"\\timer.bat";
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c "+completeComm+" "+command+" --batch");

        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));       

        LineIterator l=IOUtils.lineIterator(reader);            
        try {
            while (l.hasNext()) {
                String line = l.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                ...
                }
            }
        } finally {
            LineIterator.closeQuietly(l);
        }

        BufferedReader Ereader=new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        LineIterator El=IOUtils.lineIterator(Ereader);          
        try {
            while (El.hasNext()) {
                String line = El.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                ...
                }
            }
        } finally {
            LineIterator.closeQuietly(El);
        }


    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

My problem here is the "p.getStreamError". I can see the ouptut of p.getStreamError only if the output/result of my batch file is not hundred or thousand of lines otherwise i don't get any output(p.getSTreamError).

1. Why i am not able to get any output from p.getStreamError when the returned result/data of my batch is large?
2. When i create a jar and run it, the programs hangs forever. I debugged it and found out that it gets stuck at "while (El.hasNext())". Why does the program hang when ran through jar and works fine with eclipse?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that the individual is using Apache Commons IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use separate threads for your while loops.

Consider creating a StreamGobbler class that implements Runnable, that takes an InputStream in its constructor and that in its run method has your while loop. Then Create Threads with these Gobblers and let them go.

Something like:

```
public class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
   private static String userdir;
   private String name;
   private LineIterator lineIterator;

   public StreamGobbler(String name, InputStream inStream) {
      this.name = name;
      BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inStream));
      lineIterator = IOUtils.lineIterator(bufReader);
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      try {
         while (lineIterator.hasNext()) {
            String line = lineIterator.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            // ...
         }

      } finally {
         LineIterator.closeQuietly(lineIterator);
      }

   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

And then it could be used like so:

```
String completeComm = userdir + "\\timer.bat";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
       "cmd /c " + completeComm + " " + command + " --batch");
new Thread(new StreamGobbler("InputStream", p.getInputStream())).start();
new Thread(new StreamGobbler("ErrorStream", p.getErrorStream())).start();
```

Comment: @EJP: yep exactly! I usually use ProcessBuilder for creating my Processes, and this allows easy merging.

Comment: Thanks, the solution was to use two separate threads as you showed in the code. How can we do it with processBuilder. i tried using this code `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe",completeComm,"/C",command," --batch")` but it doesnt work.